# Magento 2 - Sales Order Address

Tags: magento2, billing-address

I want to edit the field of this column which exists in the sales order view edit billing address I want to know from which file this code is coming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically this comes from **Magento_Sales** Module.

**XML** file Path for Billing address is

```
..\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_create_index.xml
```

**PHTML** file Path for Billing address is

```
..\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\form\address.phtml
```

Only you need to Overwrite this code and Work.

Hope this will help You!!